# UIScrollView ZoomToRect is animating the scroll/zoom even though i'm sending false for animation bool

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin, core-animation

I'm trying to call ZoomToRect on a UIScrollView and I want it to NOT animate so I can wrap a UIView.Animate around it to set a custom duration.  But the problem is when I call this.ScrollView.ZoomToRect with false in the animation booleon it's still animating the zoom/scroll!  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
InvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
    this.ScrollView.ZoomToRect (new CGRect (100,100, 500, 500), false);  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the CGRect I was using was invalid.  It was a valid CGRect variable with valid float values, but it wasn't within the bounds of something (I can't recall what, maybe the superview or something). But basically if the CGRect you pass in is not valid then the animation flag gets completely ignored and it will not do what you say correctly.  So if anyone else runs into this, check the frame you're passing in.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: (tested in Xcode7.0)

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.scrollView.zoomToRect(rect, animated: false)
}
```

Using this code, I solved similar problem that UIScrollView zooms to the rect with animation even if I passed false to animated parameter(This might be a SDK bug).

Comment: > basically if the CGRect you pass in is not valid then the animation flag gets completely ignored  


Ahh this is strange behavior... Thank you, I'll try your solution :)